# Why does get_attribute return blank text between html td tags?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract details about the status of shipping containers from this website: https://esvc.smlines.com/smline/CUP_HOM_3301.do?sessLocale=en
and for example, this container #: SMCU1203410

When I use the chrome inspect tool on the website, I can see the following table data, and the text between tags that I want to extract:

```
                 <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="st_cntrNo" class="jui-border-none">SMCU1203410</td>
                        <td id="st_sealNo">SM202132</td>
                        <td id="st_cntrTpszNm">D5<br>40'DRY HC.</td>
                        <td id="st_eventDt">2020-10-05 22:20</td>
                        <td id="st_statusNm">Vessel Departure from Port of Loading</td> 
                        <td id="st_placeNm"><a href="JavaScript:void(0);" title="BUSAN, REPUBLIC OF KOREA" onclick="openLocationPopup('KRPUSHN')" class="jui-txt-blue">BUSAN, REPUBLIC OF KOREA</a></td>
                        <td id="st_piece">7 BOX</td>
                        <td id="st_weight">4,876.780 KGS</td>
                        <td id="st_poNo"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmWgt"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmUnit"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmStatus">No</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

[image: picture of website]

After I use selenium to enter the container number, this is what I'm using to get the table data:

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/div[5]/table/tbody"))).get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

but the returned table is missing the text between tags:

```
                    <tr>
                        <td id="st_cntrNo" class="jui-border-none"></td>
                        <td id="st_sealNo"></td>
                        <td id="st_cntrTpszNm"></td>
                        <td id="st_eventDt"></td>
                        <td id="st_statusNm"></td> 
                        <td id="st_placeNm"></td>
                        <td id="st_piece"></td>
                        <td id="st_weight"></td>
                        <td id="st_poNo"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmWgt"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmUnit"></td>
                        <td id="st_vgmStatus"></td>
                    </tr>
```

how do I fix this to get the status text info between the  tags?

Comment: Pls add the code that u have u tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are searching by putting container no and it takes some time to load the data it might be still loading the data in Table before you are scraping information.

You can make sure the data is loaded completely by checking any of the field from the Table e.g. Container No Cell has data or not in Table

Please check code below, it checks for the data first to make sure table has the data required and than extracts information. You can do it cell by cell or whole tbody but before that you need to wait for data to be present completely.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

container_no = 'SMCU1203410' # you already have container number

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://esvc.smlines.com/smline/CUP_HOM_3301.do?sessLocale=en")
el = driver.find_element_by_id('searchType')

#select option for container no from select
for option in el.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Container No.':
        option.click() 
        break
        
searchText = driver.find_element_by_id('searchName')
searchText.send_keys(container_no)
searchBtn = driver.find_element_by_id('btnSearch')
searchBtn.click()

#wait until table cell is available on screen
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "st_cntrNo")))

#wait until table cell has data available in it, here we are using container_no variable value to validate that
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "st_cntrNo"), container_no))
containerTd = driver.find_element_by_id('st_cntrNo')
print(containerTd.text) # container no
sealNoTd = driver.find_element_by_id('st_sealNo')
print(sealNoTd.text) # seal no

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems related to timing issue. If you will notice, your locator or xpath still exists even there's no value in tbody rows.

Before printing, try to look for below element so you would know if the data is already populated or not. This will look for the event date cell which should contains hyphen. If you encounter NoSuchElementException then it simply means that the value is not yet populated. Hope this helps on your debugging.

```
find_element_by_xpath("//*[(@id='st_eventDt') and contains(text(),'-')]")
```